# Rotating on a fixed point OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I want to simulate like a chest opening which is made up of 2 main parts, the lid and the base.

In order to rotate on the x axis, do I need to move the lid to the origin so that:
a) any corner of the lid is at (0, 0, 0) or;
b) the centre of the lid must be on the origin?

so my code looks like this:

```
- draw the chest base
- translate to origin
- rotate
- translate to original position
- draw the lid
```

Answer (score 4):

You should position the lid so that it's *pivot point* is on the origin. The *pivot point* is the point on which it rotates, in this case it would be the hinge of your lid.

As for the order of your code:

```
- draw the chest base
- translate so pivot point of lid is on origin
- rotate
- draw the lid
- translate and rotate to original position
```