# Camera Rotation with mouse stuck at origin

Tags: opengl, webgl

I'm using this for my camera

```
library.Camera = function Camera(PosX, PosY, PosZ, Pitch, Yaw){
    this.x = PosX;
    this.y = PosY;
    this.z = PosZ;
    this.pitch = Pitch;
    this.yaw = Yaw;

    this.getCameraMatrix = function(ModelMatrix){

        var TMatrix = ModelMatrix;

        mat4.translate(TMatrix, TMatrix, [this.x, this.y, this.z]);

        mat4.rotateX(TMatrix, TMatrix, degToRad(this.pitch));
        mat4.rotateY(TMatrix, TMatrix, degToRad(this.yaw));
        return TMatrix;

    };
};
```

Moving works fine, even rotating works a bit. The problem is that the rotation with the mouse always rotates about the origin point. So if I move left (-x ) and start rotating, the camera still rotates around the origin and not around the point I'm currently at.

http://glmatrix.net/docs/2.2.0/symbols/mat4.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating on a fixed point OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360107/rotating-on-a-fixed-point-opengl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should always remember that linear transformations are not commutative, this simply mean that if you rotate then translate you get different result then if you translate then rotate.

In your case putting rotation before translation should solve the problem.